# Dynamically readjusting image depending on the height

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to redo [that example](https://maximage.biz/projects/color-library#no-1) as an exercice.

I'm trying to have the image div readjusting dynamically when I click the text above or under it.

So I made a sketch to try. But I'm stuck since I don't know how to calculate the remaining space when the div `expanded` is open so the image fits in that space.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
  $("#ex").click(function()
  {
    $("#expanded").slideToggle(200)
      if ($("#ex").text() == "infos")
      {         
         $("#ex").html("close")
         $("#fit-picture").css("height", "20px");
      }
      else 
      { 
         $("#ex").text("infos")
         $("#fit-picture").css("height", "100vh");
      }
  });  
});
```

```css
body{margin:0}

.container{ 
    height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;}

#expanded{
    margin-top: 0px;  
    background: gray;
    width: 50vw; height: 50vh;
}



#ex {
    display: block;
    width: 50vw;
    background-color:darkgrey;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#ex:hover {
  background:black;
}

.container{
height:100vh;
}

#fit-picture{
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="container">
  <div class="expand">
  <a href="#" id="ex">infos</a>
</div> 
<div id="expanded" style="display: none;">the image is supposed to be reduced proportionally to fit the remaining space of the screen.
</div>
<img id="fit-picture"
     src="https://www.wanimo.com/veterinaire/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/chat-jaloux-e1574672723199@2x.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's not really adaptative and you have to define all the height before, but here is a solution :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
  
  $("#ex").click(function()
  {
    
    $("#expanded").slideToggle(200)

      if ($("#ex").text() == "infos")
      {         
        $("#ex").html("close")

        $("#fit-picture").animate({height:"45vh"}, 200) ;


       
        
      }
      else 
      { 
        $("#ex").text("infos")
        $("#fit-picture").animate({height:"95vh"}, 200);
      }
    
  });  
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, replace your image tag by the following:

```
<img id="fit-picture" src="https://www.wanimo.com/veterinaire/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/chat-jaloux-e1574672723199@2x.jpg" class="center">
```

In CSS, paste

```
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

You should mention the height & width in % instead of px. This will help to resize the image every time to resize the window. This would be the easiest way to get the work done.

Comment: i'm sorry but I shouldn't have been clear.
Have you checked the exemple I put in my question?
What I'm trying to do is to rescale the image height depending on the total height of the elements depending if they are opened or closed.

Comment: @pual -  I'm sorry if that is not what you wanted. If you define the height & width into % instead of px, that should be the easiest way to do it because it will take the defined amount in percentage & hence, the height & width changes when u resize the window.